# Switching between jpanels implementing actionListener

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am building a menu for my java game and i need to be able to switch to my game JPanel when i click a button. Here is what i have

```
public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

protected JFrame frame;
JButton btnStart = new JButton();

public Menu(JFrame j) {

    super();
    frame = j;

    //creating and styling button

    btnStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StartGame();
        }
    });



}

private void StartGame(){
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Main(frame));
    frame.repaint();

}
```

`
public class Main extends Universe implements ActionListener {

```
Timer timer = new Timer(75, this);
JFrame frame;



//@Override

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    repaint();;
    if(isLoss()){
       timer.stop();
   }
   //update cretures
}


public Main(JFrame frame) {
    super();

    frame.setLayout(null);
   frame.setLayout(null);
    //frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.map = new Map();
    StartUpHeight = 100;
    this.Size = 30;
    //this.playerCol = new Collision(map, pacman, Size);
    pacman = new Player(1*Size, 4*Size, Size / 5, map, this.Size);

    red = new RedGhost(9*Size, 8*Size, Size / 6, map, pacman, this.Size);
    pinky = new PinkGhost(8*Size, 10*Size, Size / 6, map, pacman, this.Size);
    inky = new BlueGhost(9*Size, 10*Size, Size / 6, map, pacman, this.Size, red);
    clyde = new YellowGhost(10*Size, 10*Size, Size/6, map, pacman, this.Size);
    timer.start();
    this.frame = frame;
    this.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            pacman.keyPressed(e, Size);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pacman.keyReleased(e);
        }
    });
    setUpPanel();

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    //drawing map


    //drawing pacman

    //drawing ghosts

}
```

`

I tried everything i found on the internet so far. Main extends from jpanel and implements action listener just like Menu. After this code is executed my jframe just clears. I tried to repaint it did not help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Lookup CardLayout

Comment: [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you call repaint() method you should also call revalidate() method.
Also, can you show your Main class code?
And have you added your button to your frame?

Comment: i tried to revalidate, it did not work. I fixed it by removing implementing action listener but that cut off part of functionality.